# MojoExecutionException does not stop maven compile procedure

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I've made a Maven plugin. The problem is even throwing MojoExecutionException (or MojoFailureException) will not stop build procedure!
Is any other configuration required?

```
@Mojo( name = "something")
public class CoffeescriptMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        new MojoExecutionException("Error not raise!");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<groupId>my.sample</groupId>
<artifactId>sample</artifactId>
<version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>something</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: How have you called Maven? with `--fail-at-end`?

Comment: I'm running ```mvn clean install``` and getting ```Build successful```

Comment: Do you have the code somewhere? GitHub ?

Comment: https://github.com/wpic/coffeescript-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very stupid mistake. I forgot to add `throw` at the beginning. Thanks to new Intellij for code warnings I found it!

```
new MojoExecutionException("Error not raise!");
```

has to be:

```
throw new MojoExecutionException("Error not raise!");
```